# How to Resolve Cross-Origin Issue in SAP Web IDE Personal Edition

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am writing a simple application in Web IDE Personal Edition which is to be deployed on On-Premise ABAP system.

#### App.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="databinding1.controller.App"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <Button text="Submit"/>
  <Input
    value=""
    placeholder="Full Name"
    width="50%"
  />
</mvc:View>
```

- Application Name : DataBinding1
- Application is stored in "workspace" folder.

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Data Binding1</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
      src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
      data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
      data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
      data-sap-ui-preload="async"
      data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "databinding1": "./"
      }'
    ></script>
    <script>
      sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
          "name":"databinding1"
        }).placeAt("content");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody" id="content"></body>
</html>
```

Error Message in Console:
 [image]

If I remove the `controllerName` from App.view.xml, then the view loads successfully.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your controller. Replace `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller` with `sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller` when requiring controllers, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49020578/5846045.

Answer (score 2):

You try to use the sdk provided by the sapui5 page, this is a request to another server which is not within the same system. The Error is a typical behaviour of the browser to prevent cross site scripting. 
You can fix your issue with the sapui5 proxy resource servlet for your sap resource (also works for odata, but this is another servlet => simple proxy servlet).

You should setup a resource servlet. Within your application you have to distinguish if you should use the proxy or not, check out the link:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/2d3f5fb63a2f4090942375df80abc39f.html

Remote path for sapui5 sdk stored within sap:

```
http://<yourdomain>/sap/public/bc/ui5_ui5/resources/sap-ui-core.js
```

Make sure to activate the repository in TA: SICF
`default_host>public>bc>ui5_ui5` right click and press activate

Answer (score 0):

For those who actually want to handle cross-origin resources while developing: Web IDE offers a proxy mechanism which we can leverage by adding destination files:

- [Connect Remote Systems in SAP Web IDE Personal Edition](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/latest/en-US/2cf47f37e34c428c97a51057733c0394.html)
- [Example of odata.org Destination File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938411/5846045)

---

#### For the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40101032/5846045) author:

> [...] cannot load `https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller`.

That error message shows that the browser tried to load a file named *sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.js* which doesn't exist (404). The main cause is **not** the *same-origin policy* here.

In the `App.controller.js` file, you must have defined the dependencies with an invalid syntax. Instead of dots (`.`), use slashes (`/`) in between as the API [`sap.ui.define` awaits an array of module ***paths***](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui#methods/sap.ui.define) (not module *names*).

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller" // instead of "sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  ...
});
```